# how to compare keys of an array of objects and if it has same keys how to check the value is different in that and store it in an array

Tags: angular

First i have an array of objects and also another array that have same keys but different values for some some keys in the object.How to compare these two and get the keys and values of those changed ones.

```
 [
            {

                "Salutation": "Mr.",
                "Name": "HD  ..",
                "Dob": null,
                "Gender": "M",
                "MaritalStatus": "M",
                "MobNo": null,
                EmailId": "",
                "Street": "H T PY",
                "Area": "RECLAMATION ",
                "HouseOFlat": "HOUSE",
                "PinCode": "400"
            },

                "Salutation": "Ms.",
                "Name": "HF Ltd ..",
                "Dob": null,
                "Gender": "M",
                "MaritalStatus": "M",
                "MobNo": null,
                EmailId": "                                                  ",
                "Street": "H169 BACKBAY",
                "Area": " ",
                "HouseOFlat": "HOUSE",
                "PinCode": "020"
]
```

this is my array also have another array with same keys

Comment: Would you mind telling me what the primary key of each object is? Or in other words, based on which key is one object in first array supposed to be compared to an object in the second array, so that mismatch can be checked?

Comment: actually there is no such primary key

Comment: Alright then, can you let me know if the size and order of both arrays are the same?

Comment: Which entries do you intend to compare then? Do the arrays have the comparable object at the same index? 
Would you mind posting the second array as well? What you have here now is a single array with two different objects.

Comment: the size of the both array are same and the second array have same fields and size only the values may differ

Comment: If you don't have a primary object to compare, all the keys and values of the objects would be considered as a difference and hence every object you compare would be inside your difference array

Comment: use Object.entries(yourObj) after looping over your different array that can help you to identify the entries of object in your array objects.